# Pull Latest Forum Posts within WordPress

Tags: customization

Hopefully this is the easiest question ever asked. I have a WordPress site with BBP installed. I want to be able to pull the latest BBP posts in a php query I can use throughout the site. What is easiest way of doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If they're in the same DB, it's easy enough. Pull them straight out of the DB using $wpdb. And there might even be a WP plugin or a BB plugin that does this for you.

If they're not in the same DB, but on the same server, you can access them by prefixing the DB table with the DB's name, e.g. `mybbpressdb.bb_posts`, or something to that effect.

If they're not on the same server, you need to create a new connection, using mysql_connect(), mysqli_connect() or a PDO instance. If you use either of the first two, be sure to use the parameter that makes mysql create a new connection -- else it may discard the one from $wpdb.